# How do you assign an object to an HTMLElement in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep getting the argument "Argument of type {Object} is not assignable to parameter of type string, with the following code:

```
var element = $('<div></div>').addClass('tile')
var tile = {x: 0, y: 0}

element[0].setAttribute('tile', tile)
```

For some reason Typescript won't allow me to assign the tile property that way. Is there's a way that would work? I've also tried element[0].tile = tile, and that causes the error message "property tile does not exist".

Comment: not sure, if DOM supports something like that....

Comment: Well, TypeScript tells you precisely what to do: setAttribute() expects the name of an attribute, and the value of the attribute, which must be a string, not an object (because attributes are strings, not objects). What are you trying to achieve? And why are you using `var`. Use const, or let, but not var.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to setAttribute must be a string.  If you really want to set a JS object as an attribute, you must `stringify` it:

`element[0].setAttribute('tile', JSON.stringify(tile))`

Comment: In my case, I can not stringify it : I need all class instance details, including functions. In pure Javascript, it's possible. Why not in typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

For others coming here from search results, this is very much doable without needing to serialize it to a string.

You will need to define the property in an "extension" to the existing element's interface. If you do happen to attach an object to an element like this, try to use a property name that is unique to your project to avoid collision if other scrips do that same. Ex. Instead of `tile`, use `prjNameTile`.

```js
type Tile = {
  x: number,
  y: number
}

declare global {
  interface HTMLDivElement {
    tile?: Tile
  }
}

var element = document.createElement('div');
element.classList.add('tile')
var objTile: Tile = {x: 0, y: 0}

element.tile = objTile;
// Or directly
element.tile = {x: 0, y: 0};
```